# HTTP weak Etag example,

Tags: rest, http, semantic-markup, etag

I've been trying to understand HTTP Etags and came up with an example usage. Am I correct with my thinking?

Lets say we have some RESTful API with custom link types. Some resource returns a XML data with links like this:

<link rel="http://my.api/relation_definition" url="http://my.api/resources/someId"/>

Note the custom rel definition that leads to some description of meaning of that link.

Now, if this rel description would provide a weak Etag. Programmers that create a client for my REST api could embed this etag in his/hers client. Since custom relation may mean some special behaviour of client app. Now the client app could check if link definition has;nt changed by querying with that weak etag. If it's the same, it is ok. If weak etag has changed that would mean that client may have to change/reconsider it's behaviour on these links and probably notify it's developer to take some actions.

I use weak etags instead of strong ones because I, as a provider of api could change the description of link more often, fix typos, add some examples etc, that does'nt change meaning. So I'd change weak etag of the description only if the meaning of these links is changed.

Am I correct in understanding purpose of weak etags?

Answer (score 3):

It's most important to realize that changing the ETag, whether weak or strong, will cause the browser to request the asset anew. The only difference is how much the browser trusts the ETag when you DON'T change it.

For your use case of "some description of meaning of that link", it sounds like you're talking about a small document with static (or nearly static) content, so it doesn't really matter whether your ETag is marked as weak or strong because the browser probably isn't going to do anything special that could benefit from the guarantees of a strong ETag. API clients probably don't care about weak vs. strong ETags at all.

Where strong ETags come into play is for large downloads (software, videos, audio, etc.) where the browser might use range requests to download just part of the asset. A strong ETag means that the item is byte-for-byte identical, so it's okay to use chunks of the file that were downloaded previously. So for example, imagine resuming a big download that you started last week. If the ETag was the same but it was weak, the browser might decide to redownload the whole file, whereas a strong ETag might lead to resuming the existing download.

Again, for your case, don't even worry about it. If you're using a hash of the file, you're guaranteed the "byte-for-byte identical" semantics, so go ahead and call it strong, but either way should work the same for you. Again, API clients probably don't care about weak vs. strong ETags at all.

As for when you should change the ETag, unless you're making 100 changes a day, do go ahead and change it every time you make a change.

Comment: Actualy I was thinking about semantic linking. If we have a custom relation type, identified by some url, it's URL contain some description of meaning of this relation. This description is for programmers that use my REST api.

If a programmer creates some client that performs actions on these links, then he in some way "cached" the meaning of relation in he's code. We can think about description of realtion as just another resource. ETag can identify it's version.

If REST api need to change meaning of relation, some clients may stop working properly and we could use ETag to know about that.

Comment: The main goal of ETags is really to save some bytes over the wire -- remember the UA still has to make a request either way, so for small assets, the request overhead might be most of the expensive part. In theory, the ETag would work for your relationship definition case. But I'm not sure because I have a feeling some UAs apply their own caching policies to relationship definitions, so they might ignore the ETag, Cache-Control, etc. anyway and cache for longer than you want. But that is totally just a hunch. I say as long as you implement ETag correctly, it can't _hurt_.

Comment: Personally, I would recommend to use a new URL for your definition when you change the relation enough that a an API user (developer) needs to make changes. So you have a version 2 URL, etc. This might also mean the v1 URL becomes a 404. And if you have a typo fix, etc., you could edit the definition without making a new version. If you do it this way, (1) Either strong/weak is fine; (2) you can use `Cache-Control` w/ a high `max-age` to get more performant caching behavior than ETags will give you.